# What's the accent in Oxford Advanced American Dictionary?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dictionaries, accent

Can someone please clarify if the Oxford Advanced American Dictionary uses General American English accent?

I assume it uses General American English accent which is the accent I am learning. But nowhere do they confirm that and I am confused. They only say "American English". Should I keep using their pronunciation transcriptions

Here's the link to the dictionary I am referring https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/

Comment: Accent and [pronunciation](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pronunciation?q=pronunciation) are not synonymous, but if a dictionary is titled American English it's safe to presume the system they use to transcribe pronunciation will be Standard American. NB The **red** stereo speaker symbol is AmEng

Comment: They're certainly trying to give General American pronunciations. One drawback of this dictionary is that they only ever give one American pronunciation, while some words might have two perfectly acceptable pronunciations in General American. For example, does *bog* rhyme with *dog* or with *cog*?

Comment: They do provide more than one pronunciations. Here's what they say in pronunciation guide: "If more than one written pronunciation is given for a word, they are all acceptable, but the first form given is the most common" https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english . Btw, do you recommend any Oxford American English alternatives that clearly declare to provide General American English transcriptions with similar American IPA set of symbols

Comment: You're right; I was looking at their general dictionary (where they only give one American pronunciation for *bog* and *ration*, but two pronunciations for *envelope*). If you actually look in their American dictionary, they do give two pronunciations for most words that have two, although for some reason they only give one for [vapid](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vapid?q=vapid).

Comment: @PeterShor may I know why you know they are trying to give General American pronunciations? Any official confirmations or some particular pronunciations from them let you know that? Btw, if you look at their general English dictionary, they provide North American English, because if you click on the speaker icon of each word to get their actual speech pronunciation, it shows NAmE label

Comment: There's really only one standard U.S. pronunciation that you would find in dictionaries, and that's General American. Further, they distinguish between the vowels of cloth and clot, and they pronounce pen with the vowel of pet, which eliminates West Coast, Canadian, and Southern dialects.

Comment: As Oxford is respected, and the title of the link is ... us/definition/american_english, the dictionary is announcing that their pronunciations are for General American English. They could not use the distinctive Southern, Chicago, Boston, or New York speech patterns. TV broadcasters use a Midwest pronunciation., considered neutral.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: the *vowels* of General American more or less correspond to the Midwestern vowels. There are a number of grammatical constructions and specific pronunciations of various words that are common in the Midwest (like *warsh* for *wash*) that are ***not*** considered General American.

Comment: @PeterShor Good points. Ya betcha.

Comment: Where does this come from, please? British English has - or until recently, had - Received Pronunciation (RP), said all over Google to be the accent 'traditionally regarded as the standard and most prestigious form of spoken British English' yet revealed by Cambridge.Org to have likely never been spoken by more than about 5% of England, and today about 2%.

Is the suggestion General American is an 'average' of accents from Alaska through Texas to Washington?

Should we watch M.A.S.H. and try to conglomerate Klinger with Winchester?